# Rails + Geocoder: Get users' objects around another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

My app allows users to see what others are selling (typically objects) around them.

In my first try, I get all objects using:

```
@objects = Object.all.order( created_at: :desc )
```

Now, I would like to restrict objects list to objects that are sold around the current user, using Geocoder gem. So I did:

```
@users = User.nearbys(10)
```

which gives me users around current user by 10kms. But I have to change the view because now I'm using a list of users instead of a list of objects.

How can I get a list of objects (like in try number 1) in a specific area (like in try number 2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it:

```
@objects = Object.where( user_id: current_user.nearbys(10).map{ |u| u.id } )
```

Hope it will help.